# Connect and communicate 3 android devices with peer to peer

Tags: android, wifip2p

I am working on an android project, where i have to connect 3 devices with peer to peer, and then manage to send some Text from one device to 2nd and then 2nd to 3rd. Is it possible to make connection like this. I had already created a client server connection between two device and managed to transfer text from one to other. Please help.

Comment: are the devices on the same WiFi network?

Comment: No.. Currently they are on different network, but is it beneficial if we use same network for all 3 devices

Comment: If all devices are on the same network, then you can use something like this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html Otherwise, you need a backend server to route connections from one device to another since your devices' IP's aren't going to be static.